# URL percent encoding is not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, utf-8, urlencode, percent-encoding

I'm trying to do a somewhat simple thing with no luck - I want to display Hebrew/Arabic characters in my URL.

For example: I want the URL to display a file named: `aאm.php`

So I've percent encoded the middle UTF8 characters and the result is: `a%D7%90m.php`. I've uploaded `a%D7%90m.php` to my server (Apache) and tried to request the pages www.example.com/a%D7%90m.php & www.example.com/aאm.php but my server responded:

> The requested URL `/a%D7%90m.php` was not found on this server.

So I tried to upload `aאm.php` (without the percent encoding) instead, but again no luck when browsing www.example.com/a%D7%90m.php & www.example.com/aאm.php.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: One trick worth trying might be activating a `DirectoryIndex` and seeing what URLs Apache itself serves on that page

Comment: Thanks Pekka. it sees a%25D7%2590m.php (a 25 number was added to every percent) why is that? how can i fix this?

Comment: `%25` is the hex escape for `%`. This means you've use the escaped name for the filename. You need to create the file with the real character in its name.

Comment: Alright but when i do that, apache sees the page as "aàm.php" not "aאm.php" and even when i try to enter it i get "Not Acceptable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set a mod rewrite the `.htaccess` in www.example.com. For example, if
you want your link to be www.example.com/عربية and file www.example.com/arabic.php to actually handle the request behind the scenes, then simply write this code in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine 
OnRewriteRule ^عربية$ arabic.php
```

Comment: The question was "URL percent encoding is not working". Hardcoding a specific rewrite rule is not a proper answer for other users looking for the same answer to this issue.